# Activity now getting updated after changing settings

Tags: android, android-activity, listpreference

I am working on an application that displays a RecyclerView populated by a list of movies depending on either popularity or by user rating. The user gets to choose among the two options, from a ListPreference in the settings. The problem is that after selecting the option from the setting the activity does not get updated with respect to the choice made.

The MainActivity is as follows :

```
public class MoviesScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;
List<MovieCard> movieCards = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies_screen);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),SPAN_COUNT);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    updateScreen();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateScreen();
}

private void updateScreen() {
    FetchDataForMainActivity fetchDataForMainActivity = new FetchDataForMainActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String sort_by = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.sortby_key), getString(R.string.sortby_value));
    fetchDataForMainActivity.execute(sort_by);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_movies_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class FetchDataForMainActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    final String TITLE_TAG = "original_title";
    final String POSTER_PATH_TAG = "poster_path";
    final String SYNOPSIS_TAG = "overview";
    final String RATING_TAG = "vote_average";
    final String RELEASE_DATE_TAG = "release_date";
    final String LOG_TAG = FetchDataForMainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    final String ALBUM_ART_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//";
    String [] movieNames;
    String [] posterPaths;
    String [] albumArtURLs;
    String [] plotSynopsis;
    String [] userRatings;
    String [] releaseDates;
    int lengthOfJSONArray;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String responseJsonStr = null;

        try {
            final String BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?";
            Uri builtUri;
            final String SORT_PARAM = "sort_by";
            final String API_PARAM = "api_key";

            if(params[0].equals("Popularity")) {
                String order = "popularity.desc";
                builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(SORT_PARAM,order)
                        .appendQueryParameter(API_PARAM, API_KEY).build();
            }

            else {
                final String CERT_PARAM = "certification_country";
                final String CERT = "certification";
                String country = "US";
                String cert = "R";
                String order = "vote_average.desc";

                builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(CERT_PARAM,country)
                        .appendQueryParameter(CERT,cert)
                        .appendQueryParameter(SORT_PARAM,order)
                        .appendQueryParameter(API_PARAM, API_KEY).build();
            }

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                responseJsonStr = null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                responseJsonStr = null;
            }
            responseJsonStr = buffer.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            responseJsonStr = null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseJsonStr);
            JSONArray movies = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            lengthOfJSONArray = movies.length();
            movieNames = new String[lengthOfJSONArray];
            posterPaths = new String[lengthOfJSONArray];
            albumArtURLs = new String[lengthOfJSONArray];
            plotSynopsis = new String[lengthOfJSONArray];
            userRatings = new String[lengthOfJSONArray];
            releaseDates = new String[lengthOfJSONArray];
            for(int i=0; i<lengthOfJSONArray; i++) {
                JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                movieNames[i] = movie.getString(TITLE_TAG);
                posterPaths[i] = movie.getString(POSTER_PATH_TAG);
                plotSynopsis[i] = movie.getString(SYNOPSIS_TAG);
                userRatings[i] = movie.getString(RATING_TAG);
                releaseDates[i] = movie.getString(RELEASE_DATE_TAG);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<lengthOfJSONArray; i++) {
                albumArtURLs[i] = ALBUM_ART_BASE_URL+posterPaths[i];
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "JSON ERROR : "+e);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<lengthOfJSONArray;i++) {
            movieCards.add(new MovieCard(albumArtURLs[i], movieNames[i], plotSynopsis[i], userRatings[i], releaseDates[i]));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(movieCards,getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

The SettingsActivity is as follows :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.sortby_key)));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
}

private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
    return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
            || !isXLargeTablet(context);
}

private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        }
        else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update your screen when changes happen, you should write the code in **onResume()** method:

**Replace**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateScreen();
}
```

**with**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateScreen();
}
```

Then remove from **onCreate()** the same method `updateScreen();`, so that it doesn't get called again as you will already add it in **onResume()**.

Comment: That does make sence, but the contents still don't get updated. Are there any issues with the implementation of the SettingsActivity?

Comment: I don't see any issues in your SettingsActivity. However onStart() is only called once after the activity is being created, while onResume() is called whenever the activity is restarted and reloaded, so that should have fixed your issue. Are you sure you are calling the string **sort_by** correctly?